# Java Networking - Connecting two computers

Tags: java, sockets, networking, ip-address, inetaddress

I'm trying to write a simply program client-server program that would connect a Client machine to a Server machine.

My code so far works well on the localhost, but when I replace the ip address in the Client code to the local ip address of the Server machine no connection is done. I think my understanding of `InetAddress` is off.

Socket connect code: Client.java

```
InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("my_ip_address");
Socket s = new Socket(ip, 9876); //<- where the connection timeout happens
```

Comment: @ScaryWombat yes the ports or initialised as 9876 on both the client and server

Comment: @Joni I gwt an error at `Socket s = new Socket(ip, 9876);` : `java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect`

Comment: are you trying in an enterprise network? The firewall may block for non-standard port access.

Comment: @javapedia.net I don't have the knowledge to tell you that, is there any way I can find out

Comment: Is it linux client? Try nc command like this "ncat IP_address port_number". Try for stardard ports like 80 and then non-standard port. If standard ports work then possibly firewall issue for non-standard port. if this doesn't help, use machine-name instead. Did "ping ip" work? NCAT command reference: https://www.linuxtechi.com/nc-ncat-command-examples-linux-systems/

Answer (score 5):

You don't call `getBytes()` from a `String` to get your ip address like that; option 1: call [`getByName(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName-java.lang.String-) like

```
InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
```

Option 2: construct the proper `byte[]`. Like,

```
InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] { 127, 0, 0, 1 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I found this out from another question. Now I'm getting a connection timeout

Comment: @AlexT General debugging techniques - Test locally with telnet; check firewall settings on machine acting as server; test with telnet from proposed client. You should be able to `telnet myserver 9876` and get a connection.

Comment: Debugging techniques worth more than gold these days :)

Comment: @AlexT Not really. Ping can only test icmp. Not your socket. If you don't have telnet, you can also debug with [netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) (which is more sophisticated).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch well I tried running `telnet server_ip 9876` on the client computer and I get: `Could not open connection to the host, on port 9876: Connect failed`

Comment: And what happened on the server computer? Assuming it works on the server, check your **firewall** settings.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I was running netcat on the server and nothing happens. And I've turned off my firewall...

Comment: Are you sure you're running the server? Debug until something happens. Saying "nothing happens" doesn't add anything to the description of the problem. But if you can't connect locally to your socket, then your server process may be dead; you haven't posted any of that code.